# Add class to global $post

Tags: posts

I added this code in order to customize the password protected page. I was able to add classed to most of the elements but I need to style the page title. How can I add a custom class to the $post?

```
 function my_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post" class="formpassword">
    ' . __( "Per visualizzare il contenuto di questa pagina &egrave; necessaria una password" ) . '
    <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" class="uk-input password" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" class="uk-button-primary password" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    ';
    return $o;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
```

Comment: You don't, that's not how the title output is generated, `$post` is just a container and should not be modified. There are other filters for the title, assuming that the theme provides them. You would be better using the main post classes as that on its own would be enough to style anything in a password protected post, additional HTML classes on the title are unnecessary for that reason. You can also filter those classes to add more

Comment: I see. So the title that appear in the password protected page is from another page template. The next question is how do I customize just the page title in the password protected page without affecting the page content?

Comment: The `$post` object has the title, but it's the raw title, it doesn't hold the HTML. You should never modify the `$post` object. If the theme was built correctly then `post_class()` was used and an appropriate HTML class was added to the posts main HTML tag that you can target

Comment: From what I can see (but I might be missing something) the title once rendered in page has only one class which is the same class of all the h1 title in the website. How do I target the specific title only in the password protected page?

Comment: I double checked and I found out that the theme use post_class I was able to target the title using .post-password-required class